# Why divide the output of NumPy FFT by N?

Tags: python, numpy, signals, signal-processing, fft

In many tutorials/blogs I've seen the output of `np.fft.fft(signal)` divided by the number of sample points `N`.

I understand that in some implementations that the transform is scaled/normalized by some factor like multiplying by `N`. However, I just read the docs, and by default the output of `fft.fft()` is unscaled. Yet I still see the output divided by `N` everywhere.

**Why is this?**

I have noticed that by scaling the output by `1/N` I get back the correct amplitudes of the contributing wave signals. So obviously it is necessary, but I'd like to understand what the pure output is as compared to the scaled output.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/routines.fft.html#normalization

Answer (score 3):

For the DFT to be reversible (`x == IDFT(DFT(x))`), you need to divide by `N` somewhere. In signal processing this normalization is typically done in the inverse transform. For example [Wikipedia shows it this way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform).
In other fields it is more often done in the forward transform. In physics I have seen half the normalization (`1/sqrt(N)`) applied to each transform, making them symmetric.

When the forward transform normalizes, then the values it returns are independent of the signal length (for example the zero frequency is the mean of all signal values). This is therefore the more useful variant when studying signal power.

The variant where the normalization is applied in the inverse transform (as commonly implemented in signal processing software, such as `np.fft.fft()`, and MATLAB's `fft`), then computing the convolution by multiplication in the frequency domain is easiest: one can directly write `g = IDFT(DFT(f)*DFT(h))`. If the normalization is applied elsewhere, it must be partly undone to obtain a correctly scaled result.

Other software, for example the FFTW library, does not normalize the transform at all, leaving that up to the user. This avoids unnecessary multiplications if the user wants a different normalization variant than what the library chooses.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Parseval's theorem

[image]

This expresses that the energies in the time- and frequency-domain are the same. It means the magnitude `|X[k]|` of each frequency bin `k` is contributed by `N` samples. In order to find out the average contribution by each sample, the magnitude is normalized as `|X[k]|/N`, which leads to

[image]

where the LHS is the power of the signal.

---

However, such a scale normally doesn't matter unless you care about the unit of the magnitude, like in the case of the Sound Pressure Level (SPL) spectrum.